# in python how to create a vector composed of numbers from 1 to 100 and each number is repeated 100 times

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vector, jupyter

I need to create a vector composed of numbers from 1 to 100 and each number is repeated 100 times.
I was able to come up with this solution, but I need to avoid using i,i,i,i,i,i....,i,i,i

```
a = np.zeros(0)
for i in range(1,100): 
    a = np.r_[a,[i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i]]
print(a)
```

*Here is the output : [ 1.  1.  1. ... 99. 99. 99.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.repeat` and pass `i` in your `for loop`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(0)
for i in range(1,100): 
    a = np.r_[a,np.repeat(i, 100)]

print(a)
[ 1.  1.  1. ... 99. 99. 99.]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line with [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```python
a = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 100), 100)

print(a)
# [ 1,  1,  1, ..., 99, 99, 99]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension (then cast it to `numpy.array` if needed).

```py
a = sum([[i] * 100 for i in range(1, 100)], [])
```